# XPath filtering sub node

Tags: xml, xpath

I have a xml contains following information, i am using Xpath to parse the it

```
<root>
  <a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
  </a>
  <a>
    <b></b>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
  </a>
</root>
```

my target is to get the nodelist of tag 'a' and in each sub nodelist containing 'b' and 'c' (etc. filter out 'd'!) what I am currently doing is use '/root/a' to get nodes containing all 'a','b' and 'c', then get rid of 'c' afterwards, what I am targeting to do it do the filtering within XPath instead of using extra code, is there anyway I can do it? thanks!

Comment: If my (or any other future answers) help you, please consider marking one of them as accepted by clicking on the arrow left of the answer.  This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!).

Comment: sorry, new to here, didnt know the tradition, added a bit comment on you answer, help we can have more conversation, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can filter out an element by copy everything with the pattern below and just intercept the elements you want to filter out.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">


  <xsl:template match="a/d"/>


  <xsl:template match="node() | @*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This works because special templates have a higher priority over general templates. So the second one applies to all elements except for `d` below `a`. The first template just does nothing, i.e. ignores the element.

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thanks for you help, I am receiving payload from a webserver dont think i can change the xml structure, copying xml to a new pace is too costly, the project I am working on is performance critical, so I am looking for a way to filter out tags inside a parent tag in one go.

Comment: @user1409920 This is "in one go" - I don't understand your comment, sorry.

Comment: sorry abt the english, i think i can give some more elaboration, what I am currently doing is use '/root/a' to get nodes containing all 'a','b' and 'c', then get rid of 'c' afterwards, what I was meaning is is there a way to do the filtering within XPath instead of using extra code to do it? thanks

Comment: @user1409920 Please update your question. It is hard for me to give an answer without exactly knowing what transformation you have already.